# finding $\int \frac{(1-x^2)^{n-1}}{(1+x^2)^n}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, special-functions

While trying to evaluate a different integral, I met the following integral:
$$I_n=\int\frac{(1-x^2)^{n-1}}{(1+x^2)^n}\mathrm{d}x$$
I was lost as to what to do with it, so I looked it up on wolfram alpha, and I got a result in terms of [The Appell Hypergeometric Function $F_1$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html):
$$I_n=xF_1\bigg(\frac12;1-n,n;\frac32;x^2,-x^2\bigg)+C$$
Where, for $|x|<1$, and $|y|<1$,
$$F_1(a;b_1,b_2;c;x,y)=\sum_{m\geq0}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{(a)_{m+k}(b_1)_m(b_2)_k}{m!k!(c)_{m+k}}x^my^k$$
With $$(x)_k=\frac{\Gamma(x+k)}{\Gamma(x)}$$
I found on Wikipedia that
$$F_1(a;b1,b2;c;x,y)=\\\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{(a)_k(b_1)_k(b_2)_k(c-a)_k}{(c+k-1)_k(c)_{2k}}\frac{x^ky^k}{k!}\,_2F_1(a+k,b_1+k;c+2k;x)\,_2F_1(a+k,b_2+k;c+2k;y)$$
Which I thought might be useful.

I also know that
$$\,_1F_0(1-n;;x^2)=(1-x^2)^{n-1}$$
Which gives $$I_n=\sum_{m\geq0}\frac{(1-n)_m}{m!}\int\frac{x^{2m}}{(1+x^2)^n}\mathrm{d}x$$
One could preform the substitution $u=1+x^2$:
$$I_n=\frac12\sum_{m\geq0}\frac{(1-n)_m}{m!}\int\frac{(u-1)^{m-1/2}}{u^n}\mathrm{d}u$$
But this doesn't look any better.

Could anyone provide an alternative solution or give a proof of the result given by Wolfram?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
With substitution $x=\tan t$ the integral is 
$$I_n=\int \cos^{n-1}2t\ dt$$
and it can be solved with integration by parts and recursive formula.

Comment: I feel so stupid right now. Thanks (+1)